Movie about a lady contacted by crooked police officers who pretend to help her
I'll put up all information i have about it.
It was shown on tv1000film and other viasat channels.
If I remember correctly it starts with a house/boat being rushed by Swat/FBI/police looking for "diamonds"?.
Other scenes I remember is the main character at a party mingling, then his wife asks him to tell their friends how they met, then him and his daughter travelling to their vineyard to get wine, and then the vineyard explodes. 
Later a police officer/agent/lawyer contacts the wife of the dead guy, telling he knows who did it, and then contacting some mafia. Later we find out the police officer/agent/lawyer was crooked.
The last scene is on a big nice villa with helicopters and the husband actually being alive and meeting up with them then a shoot out or something.
I don't remember the year, but I watched it before 2010.
The movie was mostly English but some lines in Italian/French.
The scenes I remember looks like it was filmed in Spain, Italy, or France. With vineyards, small and in-time streets.
The main character looks very similar to Michael Irby but taller and longer hair.

Source
His wife is Caucasian I think.

Do you remember the year/decade? Was it in english?

Welcome to Movies & TV! What country was it set/made in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.
